# Animating the "body" tag in jQuery does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So one of the buttons on my site's nav bar brings down a small grey tab from the top which tells you about the site. Here is the code I'm using for the animations:

```
var aboutMenu = function(){

    $(".aboutButton").click(function(){

        $("body").animate({top: "42px"}, 200);
        $(".about").animate({top: "0px"}, 200);

    });

}

$(document).ready(aboutMenu);
```

The idea is that the body of my website, along with all its content, moves down 42 pixels. This is whilst the content in the "about" class moves down so that it's visible on the screen. If you do click on the "About" button, all that happens is the grey tab moves down, but the body stays where it is. This would not usually be a problem, except the tab obscures the rest of the nav bar.

Here is some more relevant code (if needed):

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "about">

    <p align = "center">placeholder text</p>

</div>
```

and the actual link:

```
<li> <a class = "aboutButton">About this website</a></li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.about{
    background-color: gray;
    top: -42px;
    height: 42px;
    position: fixed;
}

.about p{
    color: white;
}

.aboutButton{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Where is the CSS for your `body`? It needs at least `position: ...` to animate the `top`.

Comment: `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` work together with `position`. Did you define that for the `body`?

Comment: @putvande thanks, that solved it. I set the position to relative and it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, to be able to animate `top` (or other positions for that matter), you need to set a `position: ...` (e.g. `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different way to call your function, e.g. add this attribute to your link: `onClick(aboutMenu())

Also try putting an allcontent div around everything and animating that, body tags aren't that good for animations

Comment: Was it really necessary to bump a four-year old post for this? A perfectly valid answer had already been given. This doesn't even mention the fact that your answer isn't correct.